# Bootstrap Tabs Not Working when code works on other site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Could someone please help I have attempted to use bootstrap tabs in a html file with bootstrap imported.
The file is here: http://spiderhouse.org/IT4/ **Note: Page no longer exists.**
The tabs appear but don't change. This is just copied code from the example page at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs 
Why do they not change?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the tabs plugin to your code

"`<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/twitterbootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>`"

Comment: That's a relative link, i do not have that file in the js folder